Regular expression to check for potential isograms C#
Suppose I need to write a method to look for non-repetetive characters (hyphens and whitespace characters are allowed to be met more than one time in an input):
public static bool IsIsogram(string word)
=> (word == "") 
     ? true
     : Regex.Match(word.ToLower(), @"^(?:([a-z])(?!=\1)(?:-|\s)?)*$").Success;

From my point of view, my pattern looks at alphabet characters and, taking lookahead negative assertion, checks if there are any characters further in the string (bakreference)?
What should I change to make it work?
To make clear, several example are provided:
IsIsogram("eleven") => false, due to several 'e'
IsIsogram("isogram") => true
IsIsogram("six-years-old") => false (2 's' characters)


Does it need to be a regex?  i would check word.Distinct().Count() == word.Count(); Missed the hyphens/whitespace part but you might simply remove them if you aren't interested in them.

"non-repetitive characters" is something else then an Isogram to me. What do you want really?

Do you mean that if there is a match for ([a-z])\S*\1 then it is not valid? See https://regex101.com/r/cPLeAV/1

It seems to me you want to disallow the same letters in the string of letters, hyphens and whitespaces, so you are probably looking for ^(?![-\s]*([a-z])(?:[-\s]*\1)+[-\s]*\z)(?:[-\s]*[a-z])+[-\s]*\z

@Ralf I though about using other methods (Linq) to check the conformity of the string's length and distinct symbols, but I wondered if it's possible with Regex.

@WiktorStribiżew no exactly. The task says that isogram is a word which has all distinct characters, but hyphens and whitespace are allowed to be used several times

You are talking about a "word" but spaces are allowed, so there can be multiple words? Can you update the question with some examples what should and should not match? Are the allowed characters only a-z spaces and hyphens? You could for example check if there is no match for ([a-z]).*\1 or ([^\s-]).*\1

So, even simpler: ^(?!.*([a-z]).*\1)(?:[-\s]*[a-z])+[-\s]*$. See https://regex101.com/r/cPLeAV/2. In .NET code, you should use \z instead of $ to avoid allowing a trailing newline LF char.

@Thefourthbird I added the examples you proposed

"six-years-old" contains two times "s", or should each part be checked separately?

@AnthonyVoronkov So if there is a match for ([a-z])[a-z]*\1 then it should return false?  See https://regex101.com/r/7xHNTI/1

@PeterB I mistook

@each symbol cannot be used more than once in a word except whitespaces and hyphens

Use Linq :
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] inputs = { "a- b- c", "a-bc ab-c", "aa b"  };
            foreach(string input in inputs )
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Isogram {0} : {1}",input, IsIsogram(input)? "True" : "False");
            }
 

        }
        static bool IsIsogram(string input)
        {
            var counts = input.ToCharArray().Where(x => !char.IsWhiteSpace(x) && x != '-')
                .GroupBy(x => x)
                .Select(x => x.Count());
            return counts.All(x => counts.First() == x);

        }

